# Why does the value of an expression depend on the variable it's assigned to?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I tried to immitate the `default` keyword of C#:

```
private class Default[T] {
    private var default : T = _
    def get = default
}
```

Then in the package object I define:

```
def default[T] = new Default[T].get
```

I expected `default[Int]` to be `0`, but

```
println(default[String])
println(default[Int])
println(default[Double])
println(default[Boolean])
```

all prints `null`. However

```
val x = default[Int]
println(x)
```

prints `0`. If I add a type annotation `: Any` to `x` it prints `null` again.

I'm guessing because `println` expects an argument of type `Any` the same is happening there.

How is it possible that assigning an expression to a variable of a more general type changes the value of that expression? I find that really counter-intuitive.

Has it something to do with boxing, so that I'm actually calling two different `default` functions (once with primitive `int`, once with `Integer`)? If yes, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: `def default[T]: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]` is shorter.

Comment: Interestingly, trying `private val default : T = _` yields `error: unbound placeholder parameter`.

Comment: @senia: won't that always be `null` and not, e.g., `0` for `Int` or `false` for `Boolean`?

Comment: @mhs: I think the rationale for that is that values cannot be reassigned, so they must be initialized to something usefull.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt True, but I would expect the first (and only) assignment to the val to be the default value for the given type.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: Yes, just like `new Default[T].get`.

Comment: @senia: Yep, I realise that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the generated bytecode, I realised what's actually happening. `default[T]` **always** returns `null`, but assigning it to a primitive calls `BoxesRunTime.unboxTo...` which converts `null` to whatever the primitive default is.

Answer (score 1):

There are not so many such classes. You could process all of them explicitly:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def default[T: ClassTag]: T = (implicitly[ClassTag[T]] match {
  case ClassTag.Boolean => false
  case ClassTag.Byte => 0: Byte
  case ClassTag.Char => 0: Char
  case ClassTag.Double => 0: Double
  case ClassTag.Float => 0: Float
  case ClassTag.Int => 0: Int
  case ClassTag.Long => 0: Long
  case ClassTag.Short => 0: Short
  case ClassTag.Unit => ()
  case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T]
}).asInstanceOf[T]

scala> println(default[Int])
0
```

Comment: Yes, that's a way to implement `default`, thanks. I was more interested in why my code failed though.